# Empty downloaded files from SOILGRIDS 250m

Tags: download, soilgrids

I am trying to download pH in water mean values for an area long = 48.2 to 48.9 degrees and lat = -4 to -3 degrees. Using the downloading tool of the portal https://soilgrids.org/, an empty file was returned. It was the same with clay or organic carbon content, and with different areas.
It is not the first time I download data for SOILGRIDS, but the first time it failed.

Comment: I am not familiar with that data portal but it seems those coordinates indicate an area of mostly ocean just North of Madagascar. Is it possible there is no data for that area? You may have better luck asking this question at the data portal.

Comment: How !!! of course! I inverted long and lat :/    Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: Happens to me all the time! Especially when going from lat-lon to x-y because I always say them aloud in that order...but it is actually lon-lat to x-y!!